# How to get the difference between two timestamps in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have these two timestamps: "08:00" and "10:40", and i need to get the amount of minutes between these two, which in the case would be 160.
Can someone please help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you attempt this yourself. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we will be glad to help.

Comment: "08:00" and "10:40" are not timestamps...

Comment: to get you started... one thing you could do would be to split the string on `:` and multiply the left half by 60, and then sum with the right half to get a minutes value. Then you just need the difference between them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly timestamps. But you can do it this way:

```
function getMinutesDelta(time1, time2) {
  const [h1, m1] = time1.split(':');
  const [h2, m2] = time2.split(':');
  const ts1 = new Date().setHours(h1, m1);
  const ts2 = new Date().setHours(h2, m2);
  return Math.abs((ts2 - ts1) / (1000 * 60));
}
```

Comment: @user1844933 that's a tough one. I'd suggest using momentjs then